# Boxplot label font cannot be set to bold

Tags: r, plot

I am making different types of plots (scatter and box) and try to adjust the font of labels. With the box plots, the `font.lab=2` parameter does not change anything. Why?

```
example= matrix(c(1,2,7,4,1,5,5,2,4,5), ncol=2)    
op = par(mai = c(1.7,1.6,0.7,0.7), mgp = c(5.5, 1.5, 0))
b = boxplot(example, names = c("1", "2"), cex.names=2.1, cex.axis=2.1, cex.lab=2.3, font.lab=2, ylab= "Percent")
par(op)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `font.lab` to the call to `par`

```
example= matrix(c(1,2,7,4,1,5,5,2,4,5), ncol=2)    
op = par(mai = c(1.7,1.6,0.7,0.7), mgp = c(5.5, 1.5, 0), font.lab = 2)
b = boxplot(example, names = c("1", "2"), cex.names=2.1, cex.axis=2.1, 
cex.lab=2.3, ylab= "Percent")
par(op)
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, it does the job. But I don't understand why `font.lab` should be within the margin settings

Comment: there's a lot of handing back and forth between boxplot, bxp, and par. Most of those graphical parameters can theoretically be passed to either function, and in the documentation boxplot should be able to handle it directly, but for whatever reason it doesn't.